# How to create 2D playing field fot a game?

Tags: java

In JAVA, I made this using Path2D:
[Before](http://postimg.org/image/g99862hd1/)

I used this code for this:

```
// First Bezier curve points
P1 = new Point2D.Double(0, 480); // Start Point
P2 = new Point2D.Double(400, 350); // End Point
ctrl1 = new Point2D.Double(50, 450); // Control Point 1
ctrl2 = new Point2D.Double(200, 260); // Control Point 2
// Second Bezier curve points
P3 = new Point2D.Double(400, 350); // Start Point
P4 = new Point2D.Double(800, 600); // End Point
ctrl3 = new Point2D.Double(600, 440); // Control Point 1
ctrl4 = new Point2D.Double(700, 310); // Control Point 2

// path bezier curve
path = new Path2D.Double();
path.moveTo(P1.x, P1.y);
path.curveTo(ctrl1.x, ctrl1.y, ctrl2.x, ctrl2.y, P2.x, P2.y);
path.lineTo(P2.x, 600);
path.lineTo(0, 600);
path.closePath();
// path2 bezier curve
path2 = new Path2D.Double();
path2.moveTo(P3.x, P3.y);
path2.curveTo(ctrl3.x, ctrl3.y, ctrl4.x, ctrl4.y, P4.x, P4.y);
path2.lineTo(800, 600);
path2.lineTo(400, 600);
path2.closePath();
```

The players will move on this ground.
My game will be like a shooter game and if somebody does not hit the enemy but hits the ground, I want to destroy the ground where the shell bangs it. Like this:
[After](http://postimg.org/image/5shedp0h7/)

How can I do this? To split the given Bezier curves and draw more is hard I think. So I thought that I will fill this area with 1x1px rectangles using arrayList and delete the rectangles from the arrayList where a shell hits the ground but I think, this is not the best solution because the arrayList will be too big and uses too much resource to refresh the painting area :( So what do you think, what would be the best solution to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use a [BufferedImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html) to hold the image of the ground.
2. Manipulate the pixel values of the image directly using its
   [Raster](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#copyData%28java.awt.image.WritableRaster%29).
3. Update the view of the image.

It is as simple as that, step 2 has many different ways of being done, but I would suggest creating a circle of radius R (depends on the size of the object hitting the ground, maybe its height?), finding all pixels that are within R of the object when it hits the ground and simply turning them white.

Edit: So here the example is, I tried finding the source for my game with no luck so here is a very simple example of a rectangle falling down on the image and destroying the portion it lands on. Note the image I used is [image]

And here is what it looks like after a few rectangles falling.
[image]

Source
**Terrain.java**

```
package explodingimage;

import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.WritableRaster;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Terrain {
private FallingRectangle rectangle;
private BufferedImage image;
private WritableRaster raster;
private int centerX, centerY;
private int[][] bitmap;
private int pixelSize;

public Terrain() {
    try {
        this.image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream(
                "before.png"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.rectangle = new FallingRectangle(getBounds());
    this.raster = image.getRaster();
    setupBitmap();
}

public Dimension getBounds() {
    return new Dimension(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight() * 3);
}

public BufferedImage getImage() {
    return image;
}

public int getImageX() {
    return 0;
}

public int getImageY() {
    return image.getHeight() * 2;
}

public FallingRectangle getFallingRectangle() {
    return rectangle;
}

public void update() {
    rectangle.update();
    if (collidesWithRectangle())
        explode();
}

private void explode() {
    int explosionRadius = 100;
    double distance = 0;
    Rectangle r = new Rectangle(centerX - explosionRadius, centerY
            - explosionRadius, 2 * explosionRadius, 2 * explosionRadius);
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            distance = Math.sqrt((x - centerX) * (x - centerX)
                    + (y - centerY) * (y - centerY));
            if (r.contains(x, y) && distance < explosionRadius) {
                raster.setPixel(x, y, new int[] { 255, 255, 255 });
            }
        }
    }
    rectangle.reset();
}

// Notice since the image we use as terrain/background doesn't cover the
// entire frame we have to use offsets, it covers the frame in width but not
// height
private boolean collidesWithRectangle() {
    int xOffset = 0;
    int yOffset = (int) (getBounds().getHeight() - image.getHeight());
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            if (bitmap[x][y] == 0
                    && rectangle.getRectangle().contains(x + xOffset,
                            y + yOffset)) {
                centerX = x;
                centerY = y;
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}


// Set up the bitmap, check if pixel colorvalue is white or transparent
// 1 = pixel is solid, 0 pixel is transparent to objects
// Assuming length of 3 is RBG and length 4 is RBGA
private void setupBitmap() {
    bitmap = new int[image.getWidth()][image.getHeight()];
    for (int x = 0; x < image.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < image.getHeight(); y++) {
            int[] pixel = null;
            pixel = raster.getPixel(x, y, pixel);

            if (pixel.length == 3) {
                pixelSize = 3;
                if(pixel[0]==255 && pixel[1] ==255 && pixel[2]==255)
                    bitmap[x][y] = 1;
            }

            if (pixel.length == 4) {
                pixelSize = 4;
                if (pixel[3] == 0) {
                    bitmap[x][y] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
```

**Fallingrectangle.java**

```
package explodingimage;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.Random;

public class FallingRectangle {
private static final int MAXWIDTH = 150;
private static final int MINWIDTH = 100;
private static final int MAXHEIGHT = 150;
private static final int MINHEIGHT = 100;
private final double MINX, MAXX, MINY, MAXY;
private static final Random rnd = new Random();
private Rectangle rectangle;
private Color color;
private int speed;

public FallingRectangle(Dimension bounds) {
    this.MAXX = bounds.getWidth() * 0.9;
    this.MINX = bounds.getWidth() * 0.1;
    this.MINY = 0;
    this.MAXY = bounds.getHeight();
    setup();
}

private void setup() {
    int x = (int) (rnd.nextInt((int) (MAXX - MINX)) + MINX);
    int y = 0;
    int w = rnd.nextInt(MAXWIDTH - MINWIDTH) + MINWIDTH;
    int h = rnd.nextInt(MAXHEIGHT - MINHEIGHT) + MINHEIGHT;
    int R = rnd.nextInt(256);
    int G = rnd.nextInt(256);
    int B = rnd.nextInt(256);
    speed = rnd.nextInt(3) + 1;

    rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);
    color = new Color(R, G, B);
}

public Rectangle getRectangle() {
    return rectangle;
}

public Color getColor() {
    return color;
}

public void update() {
    int x = rectangle.x;
    int y = rectangle.y + speed;
    int w = rectangle.width;
    int h = rectangle.height;
    rectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, w, h);

    if (y >= MAXY)
        reset();
}

public void reset() {
    setup();
}

public void stop() {
    this.speed = 0;
}
}
```

**GamePanel.java**

```
package explodingimage;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.beans.Transient;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GamePanel extends JPanel {
private Terrain terrain;

public GamePanel() {
    this.terrain = new Terrain();
}

@Override
@Transient
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return terrain.getBounds();
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

    // Draw background image of terrain
    g2d.drawImage(terrain.getImage(), terrain.getImageX(),
            terrain.getImageY(), null);

    // Draw the rectangular object
    Rectangle r = terrain.getFallingRectangle().getRectangle();
    g2d.setColor(Color.black);
    g2d.drawString(r.x + "," + r.y, r.x, r.y);
    g2d.draw(r);
    g2d.setColor(terrain.getFallingRectangle().getColor());
    g2d.fill(r);
}

public Terrain getTerrain() {
    return terrain;
}
 }
```

**Game.java**

```
package explodingimage;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Game {
private JFrame frame;
private GamePanel panel;

public Game() {
    this.frame = new JFrame();
    this.panel = new GamePanel();

    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void start(){
    new Timer(10, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            panel.getTerrain().update();
            panel.repaint();
        }
    }).start();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Game().start();
}

 }
```

Comment: hm, can you be more specific? I use bufferedImage to hold the image but how is that Raster works?
I have a run method, in which I have a game loop. In that loop I have a draw method, which draws everything on the screen. There I draw the two path. That is how I got that picture before. My players uses that path to move on the ground. I use the path.contains() method, to manipulate the moving on the surface. So how can I modify my ground, that I would be able to manipulate the movements on it, but it should be destroyable :S

Comment: I will work on an example, I used to have this in a wormslike game I made but I have misplaced the source.

Comment: Your image wasn't entirely white or transparent, in my example the image is completely white where it isn't solid.

Comment: I feel, that this will be what I want :) but give me a day, because today I wont have time to read/try this but tomorrow... :)